# Unexpected Token Import, babel-loader not working?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

> ERROR in ./app/main.js Module parse failed:
>   /Users/dz2048/myapplication/app/main.js Line 1: Unexpected token  You
>   may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | import
>   React from 'react';

I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error when i run webpack-dev-server. 
I see a lot of people have gotten this error, but for different reasons.
I suspect that babel-loader is completely skipping and not transpiling my main.js file.
First time setting this up on my own and I thought I followed the webpack docs well, but I guess not.

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "webpack": "^3.10.0"
}
```

webpack.config.dev.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './app/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../public')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

script from package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "web-dev": "webpack-dev-server --config web/webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --colors"
  },
```

and lastly, my file structure:

```
myapplication/
  app/
    main.js

  node_modules/
  web/
    public/
    webpack/
      webpack.config.dev.js
  package.json
```

web/public/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try setting to preset on the .babelrc file and remove it from the webpack config file

Comment: @monssef - thank you. I've tried this and the result was the same.

Comment: can you add your html file content also ?

Comment: it's been added now

Comment: change the preset to 'babel-preset-env' instead of '@babel/preset-env'

Comment: @monssef this makes no difference.

Comment: it should, because they're different packages, with babel-core@6 and babel-loader@7 you should use babel-preset-env, check the docs

Comment: @monssef, even though your answer didn't resolve my specific issue, you are correct "babel-preset-env" is different from "@babel/preset-env". Although I did get that from the docs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue.
My script in package.json was using `webpack-dev-server` instead of `webpack`.
Serves me right for copying code from an example project I did not fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

change the loader part to this

```
       {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
```

and I think u missed this part

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'react$': 'your react location',
        ...
    }
}
```